# What is the meaning of INT1 INT2

Tags: embedded

I have communicated with SPI I2C devices below.

- SPI is MISO MOSI CS CLK
- I2C is SDA and SCL

Interrupt is activating some code on certain event.

What is the meaning of INT1 and INT2 on the device shown below in SPI I2C communication?

How does it help to have INT1 and INT2?

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis3dsh.pdf

[image]

Comment: What part of the friendly manual is it that you don't understand? A quick text search in the pdf shows that you can route various events to those pins through software. For example if you want a GPIO to indicate free fall.

Answer (score 1):

They're outputs which can have various things routed to them, you can use them for instance to signal to the host MCU that there's data available, or wake the MCU if it's sleeping.

The possible functions are all in the data sheet.